# Selecting a row where range lies between two columns in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, range

I have 4 columns in my table

```
id , amount_from, amount_to, amount
```

My value is lets suppose 350000

The data in the table is:

[image: image of table data]

i want to query which column have a amount_from greater then 350000 and amount_to less then 350000

```
select * from table where id = 5 and amount_from >= 355000 and amount_to <= 355000
```

but i am getting 0 results.

Comment: _"but i am getting 0 results"_ - of course, because you do not have any row that actually satisfies the conditions you wrote. Or which row(s) did you think this should select?

Comment: The value 350000 lies in the second row so i was expecting the second row in the result. But 

SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=5 AND 350000 BETWEEN amount_from AND amount_to

This query works for me

Thanks

Comment: _"The value 350000 lies in the second row so i was expecting the second row in the result."_ - the `amount_from` value in that record is `250001`, which is of course not greater-than-equal `355000`. So the `amount_from >= 355000` part of your condition is not fulfilled, and since they are all joined by AND, that means the whole record does not belong into the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally you would use the keyword 'BETWEEN'

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=5 AND 350000 BETWEEN amount_from AND amount_to
```

Comment: `AND WHERE` ?? You might like to fix that :)

Comment: Thank You Champs:  this query works 

SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=5 AND 350000 BETWEEN amount_from AND amount_to